# How can one wish someone a "good night" when they sleep during the day?

Tags: phrase-request

Bob worked all night: he'll sleep from 9 am to 6 pm. What expression can one employ to wish him a "good night" right before he goes to sleep?

Comment: Related: [What should I say if someone from the opposite side of the earth says “good morning”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/52179/9161)

Comment: 'Good morning' does't imply that they sleep during the morning; 'good afternoon' doesn't imply that they sleep during the afternoon; 'good night' doesn't imply that they sleep at night. In this case as it is morning you should say either 'good morning' or 'sleep well'.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**"Good night"** will be understood, if he is heading to bed directly.

**"Sleep well"** or **"Sleep tight"** would fit better, but is more familiar. Bob's spouse might use this, but his coworkers probably wouldn't.

Comment: Sweet dreams...

Comment: I think "Sleep well" would probably by OK in any context. I agree that "sleep tight" or "sweet dreams" suggest a little bit of intimacy.

Comment: Good Night is perfectly fine here.
  
In this case "night" isn't meant to indicate a time of day, but rather indicates the customary activity of most people during the night, which in Bob's case will be done at a different time of day.  

Night in this case just acts a synonym for sleep and that will be understood by most people.

Comment: Sleep well, would be my choice too.  It doesn't come over as too familiar. No more so than "have a good evening/holiday" - you're acknowledging they will sleep, that's all.

Answer (score 7):

First thing that came to mind was **good rest**, or **have a good rest**.

Comment: I have often wished my tech co-workers "Goodnight" or "Happy Sleep" at dawn. Biological time rules, clock time does not.

Comment: Another common phrasing might be "Get some rest".

Comment: Good rest t'you, merry gentleman!

Answer (score 2):

When I was on a team that sometimes was called upon to work well into the night, coworkers often bid one another farewell with "Good work" (meaning, work is done) or "Rest well" (meaning, I'm not telling you **must** go to sleep now).

When we were feeling ill-used, folks might say a snarky: "Enjoy your time off" (as if being allowed to sleep after a long work shift were a vacation).

"I'll see you when I see you" was also heard, meaning the person should rest and relax, and not hurry back to work.

Direct references to sleep, bed, etc., are often avoided in business settings, as they are intimate subjects.

Answer (score 1):

**Sweet dreams**

**Sleep tight**  (The origin of this strange phrase is that in medieval times beds were wooden frames with ropes across them.  To stop the ropes stretching too quickly, you would de-tension them when you woke up and re-tension them at bed time.)

Not *Good rest* or *good sleep*.  Not in Britain anyway.  That's very clunky.

Comment: I would never tell my boss or coworkers  “sweet dreams” or “sleep tight”. That’s far too familiar.  I think it’s fine for family members or close friends.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who does have an irregular sleep schedule due to sleep disorder, I simply use myself (and also have been wished) "**good night**" and "**good morning**" regardless of the time of day. After all, I'm not taking just a nap, I'm having my "full night's sleep", even if it's noon outside the window. And my morning is when I wake up from that sleep, I go do my morning routines and everything else associated with morning.

I also use time dependent words like "breakfast", "lunch" and "dinner" relative to when I woke up. So my first meal is breakfast, next lunch and then dinner. So I may be eating lunch at midnight for instance.

However, whenever I'm interacting with the general public, I use the normal greeting for that time of day.

Answer (score -1):

You could perfectly say **good rest** or **good sleep**.